# can't find source of inadvertent loop

Tags: java, constructor, refactoring

I started refactoring this program I was working on and hit a major road block... I have one class that acts as a nucleus, with about 6 other smaller (but still important) classes working together to run the program... I took one method [called 'populate()'] out the nucleus class and made an entirely new class with it [called 'PopulationGenerator'], but when I try to create an object of the newly created class anywhere in the nucleus class I get stuck in a never ending loop of that new class

I've never had this issue when trying to create objects before... Here's the nucleus class before refactoring:

```
    public class Simulator
{
    // Constants representing configuration information for the simulation.
    // The default width for the grid.
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 120;
    // The default depth of the grid.
    private static final int DEFAULT_DEPTH = 80;
    // The probability that a fox will be created in any given grid position.
    private static final double FOX_CREATION_PROBABILITY = 0.02;
    // The probability that a rabbit will be created in any given grid position.
    private static final double RABBIT_CREATION_PROBABILITY = 0.08;    

    // List of animals in the field.
    private List<Animal> animals;
    // The current state of the field.
    private Field field;
    // The current step of the simulation.
    private int step;
    // A graphical view of the simulation.
    private SimulatorView view;

    /**
     * Construct a simulation field with default size.
     */
    public Simulator()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_DEPTH, DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    }

    /**
     * Create a simulation field with the given size.
     * @param depth Depth of the field. Must be greater than zero.
     * @param width Width of the field. Must be greater than zero.
     */
    public Simulator(int depth, int width)
    {
        if(width <= 0 || depth <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The dimensions must be greater than zero.");
            System.out.println("Using default values.");
            depth = DEFAULT_DEPTH;
            width = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
        }

        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        field = new Field(depth, width);

        // Create a view of the state of each location in the field.
        view = new SimulatorView(depth, width);
        view.setColor(Rabbit.class, Color.orange);
        view.setColor(Fox.class, Color.blue);

        // Setup a valid starting point.
        reset();
    }

    /**
     * Run the simulation from its current state for a reasonably long period,
     * (4000 steps).
     */
    public void runLongSimulation()
    {
        simulate(4000);
    }

    /**
     * Run the simulation from its current state for the given number of steps.
     * Stop before the given number of steps if it ceases to be viable.
     * @param numSteps The number of steps to run for.
     */
    public void simulate(int numSteps)
    {
        for(int step = 1; step <= numSteps && view.isViable(field); step++) {
            simulateOneStep();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run the simulation from its current state for a single step.
     * Iterate over the whole field updating the state of each
     * fox and rabbit.
     */
    public void simulateOneStep()
    {
        step++;

        // Provide space for newborn animals.
        List<Animal> newAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();        
        // Let all rabbits act.
        for(Iterator<Animal> it = animals.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Animal animal = it.next();
            animal.act(newAnimals);
            if(! animal.isAlive()) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        // Add the newly born foxes and rabbits to the main lists.
        animals.addAll(newAnimals);

        view.showStatus(step, field);
    }

    /**
     * Reset the simulation to a starting position.
     */
    public void reset()
    {
        step = 0;
        animals.clear();
        populate();

        // Show the starting state in the view.
        view.showStatus(step, field);
    }

    /**
     * Randomly populate the field with foxes and rabbits.
     */
    private void populate()
    {
        Random rand = Randomizer.getRandom();
        field.clear();
        for(int row = 0; row < field.getDepth(); row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < field.getWidth(); col++) {
                if(rand.nextDouble() <= FOX_CREATION_PROBABILITY) {
                    Location location = new Location(row, col);
                    Fox fox = new Fox(true, field, location);
                    animals.add(fox);
                }
                else if(rand.nextDouble() <= RABBIT_CREATION_PROBABILITY) {
                    Location location = new Location(row, col);
                    Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit(true, field, location);
                    animals.add(rabbit);
                }
                // else leave the location empty.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Here's this same class AFTER refactoring ...

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 * A simple predator-prey simulator, based on a rectangular field
 * containing rabbits and foxes. 
 * 
 * Update 10.40:
 * Now *almost* decoupled from the concrete animal classes.
 * 
 * @TWiSTED_CRYSTALS
 */
public class Simulator
{
    // Constants representing configuration information for the simulation.
    // The default width for the grid.
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 120;
    // The default depth of the grid.
    private static final int DEFAULT_DEPTH = 80;  

    // The current state of the field.
    private Field field;
    // The current step of the simulation.
    private int step;
    // A graphical view of the simulation.
    private SimulatorView view;
    //Population Generator class... coupled to fox and rabbit classes
    private PopulationGenerator popGenerator;
    // Lists of animals in the field. Separate lists are kept for ease of iteration.
    private List<Animal> animals;

    /**
     * Construct a simulation field with default size.
     */
    public Simulator()
    {      
        this(DEFAULT_DEPTH, DEFAULT_WIDTH);

    }

    /**
     * Create a simulation field with the given size.
     * @param depth Depth of the field. Must be greater than zero.
     * @param width Width of the field. Must be greater than zero.
     */
    public Simulator(int depth, int width)
    {

        if(width <= 0 || depth <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The dimensions must be greater than zero.");
            System.out.println("Using default values.");
            depth = DEFAULT_DEPTH;
            width = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
        }

        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        field = new Field(depth, width);

        // Create a view of the state of each location in the field.
        // 
        //         view.setColor(Rabbit.class, Color.orange); // PG
        //         view.setColor(Fox.class, Color.blue); // PG

        // Setup a valid starting point.
        reset();
    }

    /**
     * Run the simulation from its current state for a reasonably long period,
     * (4000 steps).
     */
    public void runLongSimulation()
    {
        simulate(4000);

    }

    /**
     * Run the simulation from its current state for the given number of steps.
     * Stop before the given number of steps if it ceases to be viable.
     * @param numSteps The number of steps to run for.
     */
    public void simulate(int numSteps)
    {
        for(int step = 1; step <= numSteps && view.isViable(field); step++) {
            simulateOneStep();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run the simulation from its current state for a single step.
     * Iterate over the whole field updating the state of each
     * fox and rabbit.
     */
    public void simulateOneStep()
    {
        step++;

        // Provide space for animals.
        List<Animal> newAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();        
        // Let all animals act.
        for(Iterator<Animal> it = animals.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Animal animal = it.next();
            animal.act(newAnimals);
            if(! animal.isAlive()) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        animals.addAll(newAnimals);

    }

    /**
     * Reset the simulation to a starting position.
     */
    public void reset()
    {
        PopulationGenerator popGenerator = new PopulationGenerator();

        step = 0;

        animals.clear();

        popGenerator.populate();

        // Show the starting state in the view.
        view.showStatus(step, field);
    }

    public int getStep()
    {
        return step;
    }

}
```

... and the new class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Color;

public class PopulationGenerator
{
    // The default width for the grid.
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 120;
    // The default depth of the grid.
    private static final int DEFAULT_DEPTH = 80;

    // The probability that a fox will be created in any given grid position.
    private static final double FOX_CREATION_PROBABILITY = 0.02;
    // The probability that a rabbit will be created in any given grid position.
    private static final double RABBIT_CREATION_PROBABILITY = 0.08;

    // Lists of animals in the field. Separate lists are kept for ease of iteration.
    private List<Animal> animals;
    // The current state of the field.
    private Field field;
    // A graphical view of the simulation.
    private SimulatorView view;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public PopulationGenerator()
    {
        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        field = new Field(DEFAULT_DEPTH, DEFAULT_WIDTH);

    }

    /**
     * Randomly populate the field with foxes and rabbits.
     */
    public void populate()
    {
        // Create a view of the state of each location in the field.
        view = new SimulatorView(DEFAULT_DEPTH, DEFAULT_WIDTH);

        view.setColor(Rabbit.class, Color.orange); // PG
        view.setColor(Fox.class, Color.blue); // PG

        Simulator simulator = new Simulator();
        Random rand = Randomizer.getRandom();
        field.clear();
        for(int row = 0; row < field.getDepth(); row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < field.getWidth(); col++) {
                if(rand.nextDouble() <= FOX_CREATION_PROBABILITY) {
                    Location location = new Location(row, col);
                    Fox fox = new Fox(true, field, location);
                    animals.add(fox);
                }
                else if(rand.nextDouble() <= RABBIT_CREATION_PROBABILITY) {
                    Location location = new Location(row, col);
                    Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit(true, field, location);
                    animals.add(rabbit);
                }
                // else leave the location empty.
            }
        }
        view.showStatus(simulator.getStep(), field);
    }
}
```

here's the Field class that the PopulationGenerator calls... I havent changed this class in any way

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Represent a rectangular grid of field positions.
 * Each position is able to store a single animal.
 * 
 * @TWiSTED_CRYSTALS
 */
public class Field
{
    // A random number generator for providing random locations.
    private static final Random rand = Randomizer.getRandom();

    // The depth and width of the field.
    private int depth, width;
    // Storage for the animals.
    private Object[][] field;

    /**
     * Represent a field of the given dimensions.
     * @param depth The depth of the field.
     * @param width The width of the field.
     */
    public Field(int depth, int width)
    {
        this.depth = depth;
        this.width = width;
        field = new Object[depth][width];
    }

    /**
     * Empty the field.
     */
    public void clear()
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < depth; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                field[row][col] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear the given location.
     * @param location The location to clear.
     */
    public void clear(Location location)
    {
        field[location.getRow()][location.getCol()] = null;
    }

    /**
     * Place an animal at the given location.
     * If there is already an animal at the location it will
     * be lost.
     * @param animal The animal to be placed.
     * @param row Row coordinate of the location.
     * @param col Column coordinate of the location.
     */
    public void place(Object animal, int row, int col)
    {
        place(animal, new Location(row, col));
    }

    /**
     * Place an animal at the given location.
     * If there is already an animal at the location it will
     * be lost.
     * @param animal The animal to be placed.
     * @param location Where to place the animal.
     */
    public void place(Object animal, Location location)
    {
        field[location.getRow()][location.getCol()] = animal;
    }

    /**
     * Return the animal at the given location, if any.
     * @param location Where in the field.
     * @return The animal at the given location, or null if there is none.
     */
    public Object getObjectAt(Location location)
    {
        return getObjectAt(location.getRow(), location.getCol());
    }

    /**
     * Return the animal at the given location, if any.
     * @param row The desired row.
     * @param col The desired column.
     * @return The animal at the given location, or null if there is none.
     */
    public Object getObjectAt(int row, int col)
    {
        return field[row][col];
    }

    /**
     * Generate a random location that is adjacent to the
     * given location, or is the same location.
     * The returned location will be within the valid bounds
     * of the field.
     * @param location The location from which to generate an adjacency.
     * @return A valid location within the grid area.
     */
    public Location randomAdjacentLocation(Location location)
    {
        List<Location> adjacent = adjacentLocations(location);
        return adjacent.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Get a shuffled list of the free adjacent locations.
     * @param location Get locations adjacent to this.
     * @return A list of free adjacent locations.
     */
    public List<Location> getFreeAdjacentLocations(Location location)
    {
        List<Location> free = new LinkedList<Location>();
        List<Location> adjacent = adjacentLocations(location);
        for(Location next : adjacent) {
            if(getObjectAt(next) == null) {
                free.add(next);
            }
        }
        return free;
    }

    /**
     * Try to find a free location that is adjacent to the
     * given location. If there is none, return null.
     * The returned location will be within the valid bounds
     * of the field.
     * @param location The location from which to generate an adjacency.
     * @return A valid location within the grid area.
     */
    public Location freeAdjacentLocation(Location location)
    {
        // The available free ones.
        List<Location> free = getFreeAdjacentLocations(location);
        if(free.size() > 0) {
            return free.get(0);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return a shuffled list of locations adjacent to the given one.
     * The list will not include the location itself.
     * All locations will lie within the grid.
     * @param location The location from which to generate adjacencies.
     * @return A list of locations adjacent to that given.
     */
    public List<Location> adjacentLocations(Location location)
    {
        assert location != null : "Null location passed to adjacentLocations";
        // The list of locations to be returned.
        List<Location> locations = new LinkedList<Location>();
        if(location != null) {
            int row = location.getRow();
            int col = location.getCol();
            for(int roffset = -1; roffset <= 1; roffset++) {
                int nextRow = row + roffset;
                if(nextRow >= 0 && nextRow < depth) {
                    for(int coffset = -1; coffset <= 1; coffset++) {
                        int nextCol = col + coffset;
                        // Exclude invalid locations and the original location.
                        if(nextCol >= 0 && nextCol < width && (roffset != 0 || coffset != 0)) {
                            locations.add(new Location(nextRow, nextCol));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Shuffle the list. Several other methods rely on the list
            // being in a random order.
            Collections.shuffle(locations, rand);
        }
        return locations;
    }

    /**
     * Return the depth of the field.
     * @return The depth of the field.
     */
    public int getDepth()
    {
        return depth;
    }

    /**
     * Return the width of the field.
     * @return The width of the field.
     */
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
}
```

Comment: First you must isolate where the problem is before coming here dumping code that may have no relevance to the problem at all. Use either a debugger or println statements to isolate it. Or if you're sure that the problem lies in this code, tell us why you think this and where in the above code dump the problem is located.

Comment: Why is your new class not included? I can't really see any loops in this code that can become endless, so maybe the problem is with that.

Comment: @Mark: I know. Right now we're kind of forced to guess at what is going on in code he's not showing us which is a bit frustrating. At the original poster: again, it will be your responsibility to do some basic debugging steps in order to try to isolate the problem, and then post **that** code here.

Comment: I did isolate the problem @HovercraftFullOfEels, I just didn't want to post everything all at once because I felt like having so much code in one post would scare away anyone willing to help...

Comment: Thanks for checking my post out @MarkM... I didn't add the new class or anything that I refactored because I didn't want to scare anyone away with a post that goes on forever... ill put up what I refactored in 2 seconds...

Comment: Just added the refactored stuff @HovercraftFullOfEels...

Comment: re, `"I did isolate the problem"` -- OK, so then where's the source of your trouble?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the inadvertent loop initiates once I create the PopulationGenerator object... When I step through the code in the debugger it steps through a small portion of the PopulationGenerator constructor, then repeatedly goes back to the Simulator class and creates new half way completed objects... It doesn't matter where in the code I try to create the PopulationGenerator either... It does the same thing

Comment: @TWiSTED_CRYSTALS: and the only thing that the PopulationGenerator does that could possibly cause is loop is by its calling the Field class's constructor, something the debugger would have shown you, and yet we see no Field class code here, again frustrating us. We have been asking you to show relevant code and yet you keep showing code that isn't relevant. Again, follow the code trail in the debugger for it shows only the truth. Do that, and you'll likely solve it yourself. Otherwise, I'm not sure how much help will be if we can't see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: Note that *somewhere* you have code that calls itself, and you have to get down and dirty into the mud to find it. There's no other way. Again, look at Fields constructor, trace through all of the code that is looping and you will solve this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thats the thing... when i step through the debugger it doesnt go all the way through the constructor of the PopulationGenerator class... Last time I had a problem and I put up all the code that I thought was relevant I got negRep'd... Now I try to keep it short and to the point and I still get negRep'd

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the Field class is up now... I do appreciate the help btw, when I get good enough I definitely plan to pay it forward

Comment: I can't post an answer because the question is closed, but your problem is not in the Field class but below it. The simulator constructor calls `reset()` which creates a new `PopulationGenerator` object, then calls `populate()` on that object. The `populate()` method calls `Simulator simulator = new Simulator();` which creates a new Simulator object which continues the cycle. Solution: don't create a new Simulator object in PopulationGenerator, but instead pass the existing simulator to PopulationGenerator through its constructor or through a setSimulator(...) method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay i see exactly what you're saying... Second opinions are always helpful... Thanks man I'll give that a shot when I get some time tonight... Is there any way I can give you credit for your answer even though the question is closed ?

Comment: Your question has been re-opened. Comment made into answer.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not in the Field class but below it. The Simulator constructor calls reset() which creates a new PopulationGenerator object, then calls populate() on that object. The populate() method calls Simulator simulator = new Simulator(); which creates a new Simulator object which continues the cycle. Solution: don't create a new Simulator object in PopulationGenerator, but instead pass the existing simulator to PopulationGenerator through its constructor or through a setSimulator(...) method.

e.g.,

```
class PopulationGenerator {
  // ... etc...
  private Simulator simulator;  // null to begin with

  // pass Simulator instance into constructor. 
  // Probably will need to do the same with SimulatorView
  public PopulationGenerator(Simulator simulator, int depth, int width) {
    this.simulator = simulator; // set the instance

    // ... more code etc...

  }

  public void populate() {
    // don't re-create Simulator here but rather use the instance passed in
  }

}
```

Comment: okay i'll give that a shot... haven't had the chance to try it yet but ill let you know how it goes... thanks again man